# Transient response for frequency dependent components

Tags: transient

For a circuit consisting of R, L and C components, the component C is frequency dependent i.e. it's value depends on the operating frequency.
I want to get a transient response for this system but not sure how the transfer function can be modelled considering this frequency dependent component.
I believe we will have unique transfer function for each value of C & hence unique transient response.
Please guide on what's the correct way to handle this where one of my passive components is frequency dependent and I want the transient response for the system.

Comment: The phrase “component C is frequency dependent” means, in plain words, that the capacitor’s capacitance (that’s what C means here!) is changing significantly with frequency. That means that the capacitor is highly nonlinear. The whole point is usually to select a capacitor that holds its value over the frequency range you need. Otherwise a more complex capacitor model is needed - a model that consists of way more than just a single capacitance. If you wanted to ask about something else, please make the question clearer.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica A frequency-dependent capacitance still describes a linear component, just one with a more complex I-V relation than \$i=C\dot v\$.

Answer (score 1):

A capacitor can be thought of as a linear time independent system that takes the current \$i\$ as input and produces the voltage \$v\$ as output. In frequency domain,

$$v = \frac{1}{j\omega C(j\omega)} i,$$
i.e. the frequency response is
$$H(j\omega)=\frac{1}{j\omega C(j\omega)}.$$

To get the impulse response, you would find the inverse Fourier transform of this function:
$$ h(t)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{j\omega C(j\omega)}e^{j\omega t} d\omega.$$

Then, in time domain, you would get the I-V relation of your capacitor as
$$v(t)=h(t)*i(t)= \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty h(t-\tau)i(\tau)d\tau.$$

For a frequency-independent capacitance (i.e. \$C(j\omega)=C\$), you would get \$h(t)=\frac{1}{C}u(t)\$ where \$u(t)\$ is the unit step function. This produces the usual I-V relation (in integral form) for an ordinary capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to know numerous discrete words in the areas of electronics and system theory but looks like your actual knowledge of the mathematical circuit analysis of LRC -circuits is very thin.

You should study circuit analysis. When engineering students do it, they reach about in one year the point where they can mathematically derive for any linear LRC circuit how it behaves in frequency domain and in time domain. They learn how to present the happenings in the circuit as state variable differential equations and how to derive from it the transfer function between the given input and output ports. Math theory of complex numbers, differential&integral calculus, solving linear equations, Laplace- and Fourier transforms and solving linear differential equations are the necessary background.

To actually answer to the question: When you write the equations for your circuit you apply Kirchoff's and Ohm's laws.

In addition you apply for a capacitor "the charging current is the capacitance multiplied by the time derivative of the voltage over the capacitor" and you apply for an inductor  "the voltage over the inductor is the inductance multiplied by the time derivative of the current through the inductor". These time derivatives take into the account that capacitors get charged or discharged and the currents through the inductors vary during the time. The electric law equations for the circuit become a group of differential equations. With it one can solve for ex. the  transient response.

You have in your head divided parts to 2 groups: Frequency dependent ones and those which do not depend on frequency. You have totally missed that the frequency dependency is not a primary thing. It's a consequence of the said time derivative rules for capacitor currents and and inductor voltages - a special case, when the voltage or current is sinusoidal.